# Stratified sampling on response categories in h2o flow data splits

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

In `h2o flow`, is there a way to ensure that my data frame splits have a controlled ratio of response classes.

For example, say I plan to train a binary classifier on a data frame X where *0_class_ratio*% of the samples are in class 0 and *1_class_ratio*% are in class 1. I want to split X into frame splits X_train and X_test by ratios 0.75 and 0.25, respectively. How would I be able to ensure that both X_train and X_test are comprised *0_class_ratio*% of samples in category 0 and *1_class_ratio*% of samples in category 1?

In python's scikit-learn package I would do something like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=rng_seed_)
# go thru all (split and shuffled) indices of my_data dataframe stratified by response_class values
for train_index, test_index in split.split(my_data, my_data["response_class"]):
    strat_train_set = my_data.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = my_data.loc[test_index]
```

I am aware of the `h2o` hyper-parameters [sample_rate](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/sample_rate.html) and [sample_rate_per_class](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/sample_rate_per_class.html), but I'm not fully sure how to use them in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `fold_assignment` to "Stratified".

[image].

Comment: This link for "fold_assignment" is slightly better (it never goes stale): http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_assignment.html